# SQL Server : 'EXEC sp_spaceused' not reporting full database size?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

Working in SQL Server, running `EXEC sp_spaceused` reports the database size as 20 GB.

But so far, I can only account for about 8 GB of that total:

- 6 GB of unallocated space
- 1 GB reserved
- 1 GB of data
- 58 MB in indexes
- 38 MB unused

What might account for the other 18 GB? Backups?

**UPDATED**

**RE TT** -- the full result of `sp_spaceused`:

- database_size: 12618.44 MB
- unallocated space: 3634.97 MB
- reserved: 1271840 KB
- data: 1179104 KB
- index_size: 58968 KB
- unused:  33768 KB

**RE sepupic** -- `EXEC sp_spaceused @updateusage = N'TRUE`

You'll notice the above values are different the the originally-posted numbers.  The revised values were the result of running `shrink` in MS SQL Management Studio.  Running the @updateusage command didn't change anything after that.

**RE TT** - "It could be the logs?"

Doesn't seem to be the case.  Running `SELECT file_id, name, type_desc, physical_name, size, max_size FROM sys.database_files;` gave the following

`type_desc  physical_name                   size    max_size
ROWS        D:\rdsdbdata\DATA\DB.mdf        624256  -1
LOG         D:\rdsdbdata\DATA\DB_log.ldf    990904  268435456`

**Progress**

Thanks for all the feedback.

Although `shrink` freed up about 8gb of space, the data, indexes and logs still don't account for the 6gb still being used.  Still looking for answers.

Comment: Hello WhatsYourFunction, can you include in your question the full resultset returned when you execute `sp_spaceused`?

Comment: It could be the logs?

Comment: First of all try to update space usage info: EXEC sp_spaceused @updateusage = N'TRUE'; Then please update your question with the picture of its output